# Actions on a binary matrix

Tags: matrix, count, binary

The plan of the castle is given, which is represented as a binary matrix of the string type:
Each binary code belongs to a specific cell. One cell has four sides, so we consider each side of the cell in the following order: left - up - right - down and set "1" if there is a wall, and "0" if there is no wall. You need to count the number of rooms in the castle, separated by walls (5 rooms in the picture).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kohif.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4WyC.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can do a 2D search with [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Iterate  through each cell and run DFS if not already visited. Each time increase the count for visited cell. The last value of count will be the number of rooms.

If the grid has N rows and M columns the pseudo code can be as follows -

```
memset(visited, 0, sizeof(visited))
count = 1
for i in N
   for j in M
      if visited[i][j] == 0
        dfs(i, j, count++)
print count
```